# detect column names and create new columns based on a custom function

Tags: python, pandas

- I am trying to make 'n' = 1, 2, 3.. number of columns named t_{n}
- t(1, 2, 3...) = p(1, 2, 3...) - current respectively
- example: t1 = p1 - current
- My problem is data is kinda messy and p1, p2, p3 can lie any .iloc (index) in the dataset. but the `p{n}` will always be there.
- I dont want to make a column if p lies in the name of other columns.
- Not sure how to best proceed further.

| current | w | p1 | p2 | p3 | other | p4 | `t1` | `t2` | `t3` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.765 | 84 | 1.765 | 1.765 | 1.765 | ad | 1.765 |  |  |  |
| 6.527 | 79 | 8.91 | 8.936 | 8.916 | ad | 8.82 |  |  |  |
| 9.429 | 79 | 8.91 | 8.936 | 8.916 | ad | 8.82 |  |  |  |

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_1 = {'p1': [1, 2, 3],
          'p2': [4, 5, 6],
          'p3': [3, 70 ,6],
          'p4': [40, 8, 500],
          'current': [500, 600, 700],
          't1': ['x', 'y', 'z']
         }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data_1)
df1
```

Comment: One question - `I dont want to make a column if p lies in the name of other columns.` It means if column is separately is omitted? Like in `data_1 = {'p1': [1, 2, 3],
          'p2': [4, 5, 6],
          'p3': [3, 70 ,6],
          'p4': [40, 8, 500],
          'current': [500, 600, 700],
          'p5': [4, 8, 500],
          'p6': [40, 80, 50],
          'other': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
          'p7': [4, 8, 5],
         )` is omitted only `p7` ?

Comment: the p1, p2, p3... they can be in any location of csv. i was thinking to specify specific ilocs to subtract, but any regex is not something i was aware of and @jezrael has clearly answered that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) wth `regex` for seelct all column with pattern `p` with digit, then subtract from right side by [`DataFrame.rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rsub.html) and `rename` columns names:

```
f = lambda x: x.replace('p','t')
df = df1.filter(regex='^p\d').rsub(df1['current'], axis=0).rename(columns=f)
print (df)
    t1   t2   t3   t4
0  499  496  497  460
1  598  595  530  592
2  697  694  694  200
```

If need append columns to original first remove `t1` column (because in sample data):

```
f = lambda x: x.replace('p','t')
df = df1.drop('t1',1).join(df1.filter(regex='^p\d').rsub(df1['current'], axis=0).rename(columns=f))
print (df)
   p1  p2  p3   p4  current   t1   t2   t3   t4
0   1   4   3   40      500  499  496  497  460
1   2   5  70    8      600  598  595  530  592
2   3   6   6  500      700  697  694  694  200
```

**Details**:

```
print (df1.filter(regex='^p\d'))
   p1  p2  p3   p4
0   1   4   3   40
1   2   5  70    8
2   3   6   6  500
```

EDIT: If need select only consecutive `p` columns use:

```
data_1 = {'p1': [1, 2, 3],
          'p2': [4, 5, 6],
          'p3': [3, 70 ,6],
          'p4': [40, 8, 500],
          'current': [500, 600, 700],
          'p5': [4, 8, 500],
          'p6': [40, 80, 50],
          'other': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
          'p7': [4, 8, 5],
         }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data_1)
print (df1)
   p1  p2  p3   p4  current   p5  p6 other  p7
0   1   4   3   40      500    4  40     x   4
1   2   5  70    8      600    8  80     y   8
2   3   6   6  500      700  500  50     z   5
```

---

```
pos = df1.columns.get_indexer(df1.filter(regex='^p\d').columns)
print (pos)
[0 1 2 3 5 6 8]

s = pd.Series(pos).diff().ne(1).cumsum().duplicated(keep=False)
print (s)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool

df = df1.iloc[:, pos[s]]
print (df)
   p1  p2  p3   p4   p5  p6
0   1   4   3   40    4  40
1   2   5  70    8    8  80
2   3   6   6  500  500  50
```